# Jquery validation not working - adding input dynamically

Tags: jquery, validation

I have this script:

http://jsfiddle.net/5RrGa/1619/

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#prihlaska').validate({ // initialize the plugin
                rules: {
                    jmeno: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    prijmeni: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    jmeno: {
                        required: "Vyplňte vaše jméno."
                    },
                    prijmeni: {
                        required: "Vyplňte vaše příjmení."
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: "Vyplňte vaši emailovou adresu.",
                        email: "Zadejte platnou emailovou adresu."
                    },
                    jmeno_ucastnik: {
                        required: "Vyplňte jméno účastníka.",
                    }
                }

            });

        });

 $("select[name=listku]").change(function() {
    var pocetInputu = $("#jmena input").length;
    var pozadovanyPocet = $(this).val()-1;
    rozdil = pozadovanyPocet - pocetInputu;
    if(rozdil > 0)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < rozdil; i++) {
        $("#jmena").append('<div class="form-group">' +
                            '<label for="jmeno" class="sr-only">Jméno účastníka</label>' +
                            '<input type="text" class="form-control"  name="jmeno_ucastnik[]" placeholder="Jméno účastníka">' +
                           '</div>');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $("#jmena input").slice(pozadovanyPocet).remove();
    }
})
```

Where I can add new input with `name="jmeno_ucastnika[]"` by JQuery, but for some unknown reason the validation for this input is not working (for input with name `jmeno`, `prijmeni` and email working).

Answer (score 1):

You are adding control dynamically. So it is better that make a validate function and after adding the new controls, bind the validate event again with new element or with all elements. It is upto you.

You can do something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
doValidate();
        });


function doValidate(){
console.log("doValidation");
            $('#prihlaska').unbind("validate").validate({ // initialize the plugin
                rules: {
                    jmeno: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    prijmeni: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    jmeno_ucastnik: {
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    jmeno: {
                        required: "Vyplňte vaše jméno."
                    },
                    prijmeni: {
                        required: "Vyplňte vaše příjmení."
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: "Vyplňte vaši emailovou adresu.",
                        email: "Zadejte platnou emailovou adresu."
                    },
                    jmeno_ucastnik: {
                        required: "Your Validation Text here.",
                    }
                }

            });

}

 $("select[name=listku]").change(function() {
    var pocetInputu = $("#jmena input").length;
    var pozadovanyPocet = $(this).val()-1;
    rozdil = pozadovanyPocet - pocetInputu;
    if(rozdil > 0)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < rozdil; i++) {
        $("#jmena").append('<div class="form-group">' +
                            '<label for="jmeno" class="sr-only">Jméno účastníka</label>' +
                            '<input type="text" class="form-control"  name="jmeno_ucastnik" placeholder="Jméno účastníka">' +
                           '</div>');
        }

    }
    else
    {
        $("#jmena input").slice(pozadovanyPocet).remove();
    }
    doValidate();
});
```

The jsFiddle is updated. You can test it there too.

http://jsfiddle.net/5RrGa/1620/

Comment: This validate just first input with name="jmeno_ucastnik"

Comment: I know. But I have given you hint that how can you perform this activity. If you want on all controls then you can customize your doValidate() function with some parameters.. Else you can extend the validate parameter object (by making it global) and then call again the doValidate() fucntion then it will work definitely.

Comment: Yeah, i know what you mean (I hope :) ) - there is my edit: http://jsfiddle.net/5RrGa/1621/. But still I can validate input with name="jmeno_ucastnik_1" (2, 3, ...)

Comment: You have to properly add the attributes to your validate function object. check now and upvote for the answer :-) http://jsfiddle.net/5RrGa/1622/

Answer (score 0):

jquery.validate requires that every input have a unique name. So instead of having names like

```
jmeno_ucastnik[]
```

you need to put explicit counters into the brackets. The initial HTML should use name=jmeno_ucastnik[0], and the Javascript that adds rows can increment it.

```
var counter = 0;
$("select[name=listku]").change(function() {
var pocetInputu = $("#jmena input").length;
var pozadovanyPocet = $(this).val()-1;
rozdil = pozadovanyPocet - pocetInputu;
if(rozdil > 0)
{
 counter++;
    for (var i = 0; i < rozdil; i++) {
    $("#jmena").append('<div class="form-group">' +
                        '<label for="jmeno" class="sr-only">Jméno účastníka</label>' +
                        '<input type="text" class="form-control"  name="jmeno_ucastnik['+counter+']" placeholder="Jméno účastníka">' +
                       '</div>');
    }
}
else
{
    $("#jmena input").slice(pozadovanyPocet).remove();
}
```